# nhibernate exception - External component has thrown an exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I have started to get this exception:

External component has thrown an exception

cause by this code:

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = NHibernateSession.Init(
                    new SimpleSessionStorage(),
                    mappingAssemblies,
                    new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
                    configFile);
```

This used to work fine. This is the stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CreateFile(String lpFileName, Int32 dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, Int32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SafeCreateFile(String lpFileName, Int32 dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, Int32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.EnsureTempNameCreated()
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.AddExtension(String fileExtension, Boolean keepFile)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.AddExtension(String fileExtension)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration..ctor(SettingsFactory settingsFactory)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration..ctor()
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.ConfigureNHibernate(String cfgFile, IDictionary`2 cfgProperties)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.AddConfiguration(String factoryKey, String[] mappingAssemblies, AutoPersistenceModel autoPersistenceModel, String cfgFile, IDictionary`2 cfgProperties, String validatorCfgFile, IPersistenceConfigurer persistenceConfigurer)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.Init(ISessionStorage storage, String[] mappingAssemblies, AutoPersistenceModel autoPersistenceModel, String cfgFile, IDictionary`2 cfgProperties, String validatorCfgFile, IPersistenceConfigurer persistenceConfigurer)
   at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.Init(ISessionStorage storage, String[] mappingAssemblies, AutoPersistenceModel autoPersistenceModel, String cfgFile)
```

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More people getting the error here... http://forums.asp.net/p/1704958/4534454.aspx/1?Re+SEHException+thrown+when+I+run+the+application

Comment: I have done this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653950/external-component-has-thrown-an-exception and received First-chance exception at 0x77c200b6 in devenv.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.

Comment: Your post really helped so I accept it. Removing trusteer rapport worked for me!